# UIKeyCommand with modifier won't be recognized on first invocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard-shortcuts, uikeycommand

I support keyboard shortcuts in my iOS app through serving `UIKeyCommand` instances from my view controller.

The following works like a charm and causes the provided selector to be invoked every time you press <kbd>e</kbd>:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[
        [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"e" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(foo:)]];
    ];
}
```

However, I want the key command to be <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, or

```
[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"e" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(foo:)]
```

This still works, kind of. **It won't work the first time** you press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, but it will work like a charm after that. Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known bug. As a workaround, you can register to respond to *just the Command key* by passing in an empty string and a selector that does nothing:

```
[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@""
                    modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand 
                           action:@selector(doNothing:)]
```

Then, by the time the user hits <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, it'll be the second invocation and it'll register fine.

More information on the bug can found [here on OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/19613391). It was submitted on January 27, 2015, and marked as a duplicate on February 24.